# How to get channel of command used | discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

If someone send a command in lets say the general channel, how would i get that channel. Like ctx.author.voice.channel, is there a way to use ctx.author to get the text channel?

Comment: should just be attached to the message. so `message.channel`. Some discord functionality returns `members`, others return `users`. A skim through the documentation is a good idea.

Comment: @TheLazyScripter `@bot.event
async def on_button_click(interaction):
    if interaction.component.label.startswith("play"):
        channel = interaction.author.text.channel
        await channel.send("Playing music " + interaction.author.mention)` im trying to get the channel from an interaction with a button

Comment: I've never seen the on_button_click bot event. Is it a documented event in the discord.py docs?

Comment: @EricB its part of discord-components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `ctx.author` to get the channel, because **discord.Members** and **discord.Users** are not channel specific. You can however, use `ctx.channel` to get the channel the command was used in.

You can use:

```py
@bot.command()
async def get_this_channel(ctx):
    channel = ctx.channel
    # .. do things
```

With that being said, this is separate from Views with [discord.py 2.0](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py), which allow for 1st party support of buttons and drop down menus.

Please do not use third party libs for buttons when they're already worked into Discord.py 2.0... they're bad.

Check out this example of a simple button using [discord.py 2.0](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py)

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class ThisUI(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    @discord.ui.button(label='Test button!')
    async def test_button(self, button, interaction):
        channel = interaction.channel
        
        if channel is not None:
            await channel.send('Hello from a button!')

class Commands(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        
    @commands.command()
    async def testbuttons(self, ctx):
        return await ctx.send("Hey now!", view=ThisUI())
```

Please view both the [documentation for this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#discord.ui.View), and some [examples](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/master/examples/views) from the repository

Answer (score 0):

Well you cant use **ctx.author** or `user` as they are not channel specific.

Here is a simple snippet you can use.

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    channel = ctx.channel
    await ctx.channel.send('test')
```